# Twistd socket ownership

Tags: python, twisted, unix-socket, twistd

I have a daemon which listens to a socket in `/var/run`. I start the daemon using an init script (as root, obviously), and I'm using the `twistd` `--uid` and `--gid` options to drop privileges to an unprivileged user.  The socket, however, is still owned by `root:root`.

A second daemon, which runs as the same unprivileged user, needs to have access to the socket. I now change the socket ownership to `daemon:daemon` in the init script, but this doesn't strike me as a very elegant solution.

Is there a way make the socket owned by `daemon:daemon` in the `tac` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently there isn't.

It's an open issue in Twisted, it's also the case with PID and log files.

See [blog describing the issue](http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=526), and open issues:

- http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/5297
- http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/5296